# How do I export a steam game into a unity package

Tags: unity-game-engine, steam

I've been wanting to mod hollow knight for a while now and since I have recently gained experience with the unity game engine I thought I would try it out. The only problem is I can't really find a way to export the files into unity and so far have found no tutorials online maybe exporting it into a package is not the answer so I'm just curious on how to import the files into unity.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really how game modding works. You won't be able to import the compiled game's assets into Unity. If the game uses the Mono runtime (not IL2CPP), you can find the DLL files that contain the game's logic, decompile them (using a decompiler like dotPeek), make modifications to the game's source code (for example, adding your own logic to change behavior and load additional assets), recompile the code, and replace the game's original DLLs with your modified version.